# How do you get a variable exposed from Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I've been programming for almost 30 years and this has me pulling my hair out like nothing before. I've tried zillions of permutations of build tools and versions of babel and webpack and different stupid hacks and nothing works.

I'm writing a library. I'm using Babel to transpile and then Webpack to assemble a final .js file for the user to import. Naturally, I want to expose some things into the global namespace for the user to use. That's what I'm trying to figure out here.

How the hell am I spuposed to do this? I can obviously just set `window.whatever=thing` but that seems cheap. I'm trying to use the `library` config entry in the webpack.config.js file, but the object I name there is always empty, regardless of what I return in what file.

Also, when I use babel-preset-env I get an error about regeneratorRuntime isn't defined. This feels kind of like more of a disaster than it should be... am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a necessity to put anything in the global namespace? You could export an object as the namespace of the library with variables and multiple functions set?

Comment: How do you want your users to use/import your library? Webpack *does* have an option to just register `window.x` because it's pretty much the traditional way to do this. I would not do this in your code, but do it with Webpack configuration.

Comment: But now you also have a new option, Ecmascript modules. But if you just want a traditional script tag which creates a globally available namespace for your library, Webpack will register your library on `window.`

Comment: @Evert as Narigo suggests I'd rather just have a single variable like $ in jquery exposed and define whatever I need inside there. But i've tried so many permutations of how to set this up and everything seems to have one problem or another. what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: So even jQuery's `$` is _actually_ just `window.$`. Same thing!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes looking for an answer, here it is!

The issue seems to have to do with the way I was going from JS to Babel to Webpack -- instead, I switched to use `babel-loader` so the only build command I need is `webpack`, which runs Babel itself as needed -- when I ran it like this, everything exports as expected to the symbol named by `library`.